# Redirecting standard output of CreateProcess() to a pipe and reading it in another process in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, pipe, stdout, io-redirection, createprocess

I have a main C++ program. This program, at its startup, launches another process executable using CreateProcess() function. Now I want to redirect the standard output (stdout) of this new process to the main C++ program. For this purpose I would like to use a pipe in Windows. I am able to achieve this in Linux using [fork()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) and pipe(), but I am unable to get CreatePipe() working on Windows. The pipe is created, but I am unable to get any data.

What could be some example or sample code for this purpose? I have successfully redirected the standard output of CreateProcess to a file, but the pipe does not work.

Comment: tried flushing the output from the output stream ?

Comment: [Sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5488264/179910).

Comment: Try using some stuff mentioned in here. stringstream is your choice. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-a-string