# get stderr and stdout to string in ShellExecute function

Tags: c, windows

I want to get the `stderr` and the `stdout` from excusing commands in console to x string in order to do some codes in certain `stderr` and `stdout` cases

```
case WM_CREATE:
            ShellExecute(0,
                         "open",
                         "cmd.exe",
                         "/C ipconfig > x",
                         0, SW_HIDE);
break;
```

that out result to x file also I think it is not recording stderr as it leaves the x file empty on excusing adb command

Comment: It takes a fair bit more code than what you have shown. :-) See here for a sample: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process output c Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486762/process-output-c-windows)

Answer (score 0):

@CodyGray, thank you for trying to help, I found the solution is to just add "2>&1" this will catch stderr and stdout like this

```
ShellExecute(0,
                         "open",
                         "cmd.exe",
                         "/C ipconfig > buffer.txt 2>&1",
                         0, SW_HIDE);
```

the solution is more simpler than what you have mentioned just need to find out how to redirect it to string

Comment: Well, if it were really that simple, no one would waste time writing all that code. Sure, the `2>&1` magic can redirect stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1), but you keep oversimplifying the problem. There is no "just" redirecting it to a string. You have to read the data out of the stdout handle into a string yourself.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you that was right, I will try to code your mentioned code or read the file