# How to execute commands in an external process and capture its output?

Tags: c++, shell, chess, stockfish

I am trying to write a function that can interact with StockFish (a chess engine) and store the output somewhere. If you download StockFish, there is a .exe you can run and it opens a shell program where you give some commands and it outputs some text (like the best move). The issue I am having is that, I am able to write commands, but I can't read them.

This is my code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> stockFishPerft(std::string fenString, int depth) {
    const char* stockfishPath = R"(C:\Users\1flor\CLionProjects\Chess\src\utils\stockfish\stockfish-windows-x86-64-avx2.exe > nul)";
    FILE* stockfishProcess = popen(stockfishPath, "w");
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> moveCounts;

    if (!stockfishProcess) {
        std::cout << "Error: Could not open Stockfish process." << std::endl;
        return moveCounts;
    }

    std::string positionCommand = "position fen " + fenString + "\n";
    std::string perftCommand = "go perft " + std::to_string(depth) + "\n";

    std::fprintf(stockfishProcess, "%s", positionCommand.c_str());
    std::fflush(stockfishProcess);

    std::fprintf(stockfishProcess, "%s", perftCommand.c_str());
    std::fflush(stockfishProcess);

    char buffer[4096];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stockfishProcess) != nullptr) {
        std::cout << buffer;  // Print raw output
    }

    pclose(stockfishProcess);

    return moveCounts;
}
```

When I run this, nothing gets printed. Now I have to confess that this was largely written with ChatGPT, because I don't have that much experience with C++ and I have never done something like this before. I think the reason why I can't read it because of this line:

```
FILE* stockfishProcess = popen(stockfishPath, "w");
```

Because I open this in "write" mode. But if I open it in "read" mode, I can't write my commands to StockFish. I saw something about opening it in "r+" mode, where you can read and write, but if I try that, it doesn't open the StockFish process successfully.

I did find some stuff online, but the code was very long and hard to understand. I feel like this is quite a simple task, so I figured I would ask here first, before I start writing code that felt overly complicated and stupid.

Comment: `popen` is either for writing __or__ reading. You have to use something else if you want to do both.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a C++ developer. A C++ developer would know what `popen` does, and what the `"w"` parameter means to popen, and why attempting to `fgets` from the resulting file pointer is an excersize that's doomed to failure. There are, unfortunately, no shortcuts to learning C++. It takes 3-5 years of intense study, using a good textbook. A dumb chatbot will not reduce that time to minutes. This entire approach is fundamentally flawed. One needs to use operating system-specific libraries to create a pseudo-terminal device, and run the wrapped program in it.

Comment: If you find a similar example online, take that, compile it and then run it in a debugger to experience it in action. Adapt that to control e.g. stockfish instead. Keep record of your attempts (e.g. using Git), so you can retrace your steps.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ... I'm just trying to write a function that can interact with a shell program. I know ChatGPT is not a c++ developer and I know I'm not going to become an expert in C++ using it, nor was that my intention. I am not a c++ dev, nor do I want to be, this is just something I am doing for fun. I didn't ask for a lecture, I asked for help. Chill

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you know what else? A keyword that I can google would be nice.

Comment: Hi. You seem to be on Windows. I know nothing about windows. On Linux you can use `pipe` with `fork` and `exec`. Research "how to run a process for writing and reading from C++ on windows".

Comment: Well, here's the right direction that I already mentioned: use your OS-specific libraries to create a pseudo-terminal device, and run your chess program attached to the pseudo-terminal, which your C++ code will control. This all assumes that the chess program does utilize standard output/input, and does not write to the real terminal console directly. One might try attaching pipes to both standard output and input, and try that. Only a small chance that'll work, given the obvious buffering issues. It's likely that non-blocking I/O will be required to deal with it. You're all set now?

Comment: Because, you see, most C++ libraries detect if standard output is attached to a real terminal, and then enable automatic flush at end of line. Otherwise, the program's output gets buffered, until the output buffer, typically 4096 or 8192 bytes is filled, then the whole thing gets flushed. So your program might be vainly trying to control your chess program's input, by feeding it to standard input, but there's no output. It's getting buffered. That's why a pseudo-terminal device is often necessary. So, you see, C++ is not as easy as running a Google search, and copy/pasting the results.

Comment: For either input or output, you can use `_popen`. But if you want to use both, you must either [use Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486814/509868) or find a library on the Internet which does that for you. The problem with read+write is that it's impossible to get right (i.e. without deadlocks) in the general case, so making a library which does that would be annoying to self (people would complain that it deadlocks).

Comment: And, to close the books: that's not the reason why the shown code is broken. It's broken from the start by opening only a write pipe to the chess program, and trying to read from it. But the point is, even after getting this right: there's a fairly good chance that it won't work anyway. Maybe it will, but now there are deadlocks! Yay! So, take your pick: learn how to do non-blocking I/O, and I/O multiplexing, or learn how to use a pseudo-tty emulation layer. It's actually lots of fun learning all of this stuff, so if you're looking to have fun, you're actually in the right place. C++ is fun.